# Can dependency injection save memory space?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am having a large array of large objects in a C# server application. A lot of object properties have usually default values.

Is it worth looking at trying dependency injection to optimize or reduce memory usage in my application?

Comment: Sorry, clueless: how would that work? You'd template your array on an interface instead and instantiate one of a set of different object depending on which properties have non-null values? Can DI do that automatically? I thought it was for abstracting application-level services.

Comment: i read somewhere that it allows properties to be injected on an as needed basis, thus was thinking that it would save memory.

Answer (score 6):

This is only loosely related to dependency injection - you can factor out the commonality and use the *same* **immutable** object instance to represent the shared state. How you create/access this shared object (also see [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)) is another thing, as suggested it could be via DI or a factory method.

Comment: I agree. It's not that much that Dependency Injection will reduce memory, but because you'll end up with an application that is much easier to adapt to change, it is much easier to solve performance and memory problems when they occur.

Comment: i am confused because wpf property system claims to reduce memory , and it is based on dependency injection. hence i was thinking that dependcy injection might be doing the trick. please advice what am i missing to understand

Comment: @fruit_trader: I think what you are referring to is how WPF actually determines what the *value* of a dependency property is - if an object does provide a different value the lookup goes on to check the current animation, inherited values, templated parent, styles etc. - so the same property object can be used by many different controls if they use the same setting.